# Websocket not working on my Android app (with Phonegap Build)

Tags: android, cordova, websocket, phonegap-build

I tried to develop a simple mobile application that connect to a websocket server. I used *Phonegap Build* to make my Android .apk, here's the *html* code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing websockets</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var webSocket = 
  new WebSocket('ws://192.168.82.1:8080/WebSocket/websocket');

webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
  onError(event)
};

webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
  onOpen(event)
};

webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  onMessage(event)
};


function onMessage(event) {

    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML 
    += '<h1 align="center"/>' +"    "+ event.data;   

}

function onOpen(event) {

  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML 
  += '<h1 align="center"/>connection established';
}

  function onError(event) {
  alert(event.data);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is working fine on my navigator but the message "connection established" doesn't even appear when I use the Android app.
Is there something wrong with this code or does my app need some library ?

**PS :** I have another code with a button sending a message to the server and receiving a text from it, and of course it's the same problem !

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets are only supported in WebView after Android 4.4. So if you want to use it in older android versions ,you have some choices:

- Use a Cordova plugin that provides that functionality. For example, https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android (this is just an example, I have never worked with that plugin)
- Use something like [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) or [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to provide webSockets when supported and fallback to other technologies when not. Please note that using those technologies requires you to use them also in the server

Comment: Thanks, I also found that there is a PhoneGap Build WebSocket plugin on their repo. I will try both solutions !