# ionic2 WebSocket is not working in Android App

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, websocket, ionic2

Trying to get WebSocket work in an ionic2 Android app.
**In browser mode it is working fine**.

I installed https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android and followed all the instructions:
- installed cordova-plugin-whitelist
- set a Content-Security-Policy (CSP)
- set config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="ws://*/*:*"/>
<allow-intent href="wss://*/*:*"/>
```

But there is no connection to my server when i test with *ionic run android*

```
connect(){
this.ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.178.170:8000");

this.ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('open');
};

this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log('new message: ' + event.data);
  this.messages.push(event.data);
};

this.ws.onerror = () => {
  console.log('error occurred!');
};

this.ws.onclose = (event) => {
  console.log('close code=' + event.code);
  this.connect();
};
```

Did i missed something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websocket not working on my Android app (with Phonegap Build)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998548/websocket-not-working-on-my-android-app-with-phonegap-build)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Ionic 2, but at least in Corova, a CSP meta tag is enabled in html pages by default. If the tag is set in your html page, you need to append a directive to it to allow WebSocket access.

For instance:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src ws://192.168.178.170:8000">
```

Take notice of the end of the above.